# cron job- can't understand scheduled time

Tags: crontrigger

I see a cron job scheduled using this time H(0-29) 14 * * 4-5 in my application config. I see last part is about Thursday-friday but can't understand the other part. Please help me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

0-29 14 * * 4-5
“At every minute from 0 through 29 past hour 14 on every day-of-week from Thursday through Friday.”

Take a look at this resource for an easy Crontab understanding.
https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Was it helpful?

Comment: it was, thank you. But it is used in deployment script job, so thinking why is 0-29 used i.e deploy at every minute from 0 through 29